# PostgreSQL - Unexpected division by zero using SUM

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

This query (minimal reproducible example):

```
WITH t as (
    SELECT 3 id, 2 price, 0 amount
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN
        SUM(price / amount)
    ELSE
        price
    END u_price
FROM t
GROUP BY id, price, amount
```

on PostgreSQL 9.4 throws

> division by zero

Without the `SUM` it works.

How is this possible?

Comment: The same behavior on PostgreSQL 10 (10.3).

Comment: Seems to have something to do with the CTE, because `... FROM ( values (3, 2, 0) ) as t(id, price, amount) ...` works correctly. Might be worth [logging as a bug](https://www.postgresql.org/account/submitbug/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I liked this question and I turned for help to these [tough guys](https://postgrespro.com/) :

**The planner is guilty:**

> A CASE cannot prevent evaluation of an aggregate expression contained
>   within it, because aggregate expressions are computed before other
>   expressions in a SELECT list or HAVING clause are considered

More details at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure the "why" part out, but here is a workaround...

```
 WITH t as (
      SELECT 3 id, 2 price, 0 amount
 )
 SELECT  SUM(price / case when amount = 0 then 1 else amount end) u_cena
 FROM t
 GROUP BY id, price, amount
```

OR: you can use the following and avoid the "case"

```
 SELECT  SUM(price / power(amount,sign(amount))) u_cena
 FROM t
 GROUP BY id, price, amount
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with using a "sum" inside the result.. that seems like it'd be a logical black hole to me, but I'm not 100% sure.. just call it Oracle Certified DBA's intuition.